# Failing to start a Scrapy project within Windows Ubuntu WSL using virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm quite new to Scrapy and found this error baffling me big time. I work on a Windows machine and use a Ubuntu subsystem (WSL) to do all my development work. I have created a virtual environment and trying to start learning Scrapy, however, whenever I am in the virtual environment and try to create a new project, the following error shows up and the files cannot be created successfully.

OS: Windows 10

Environment: Windows 10 - WSL Ubuntu 20.04.1

Python: Python 3.8.5

Recreate issue:

```
python3 -m venv /Directory/
source /Directory/bin/activate
(venv) pip install scrapy
(venv) scrapy startproject /directory/
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../bin/scrapy", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 145, in 
execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 100, in 
_run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 153, in 
_run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 110, in run
    self._copytree(self.templates_dir, abspath(project_dir))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 83, in _copytree
    self._copytree(srcname, dstname)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 83, in _copytree
    self._copytree(srcname, dstname)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/commands/startproject.py", line 88, in _copytree
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 376, in copystat
    _copyxattr(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 326, in _copyxattr
    os.setxattr(dst, name, value, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/c/Users/.../module/spiders'
```

The strange thing is that when I am not using a virtual environment, it works just fine. Is there any way I could fix this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
python3 -m venv /Directory/
```

Try

```
python3 -m venv Directory
```

The former one puts your virtual environment as directory under / instead of in the current directory.

(Please don't call your virtual environment Directory ;) )